# How to select an li with jQuery using multiple data-attributes and multiple logical conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I' ve got a productlist that i'd like to filter clientside. The productlist is an ul with multiple li's like this one:

```
<li data-property="2,3,4" data-format="1,2,3,4,5" data-location="1,2,4" data-id="9">
                        Product A is fantastic 
</li>
```

Using jQuery how can I select the li's that have for example:
(value 2 OR 4 in data-location) AND (value 3 OR 4 in data-property) AND (value 1 OR 2 OR 3 in data-location).

Comment: if this would make the solution easier, the data-attributes could use a space-delimiter instead of a comma-delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a custom expression:

```
$.expr[':'].myProductFiltered = function(obj){
  var $obj = $(obj),
      d_p = $obj.data('property').split(','),
      d_f = $obj.data('format').split(','),
      d_l = $obj.data('location').split(',');

  return ($.inArray("3", d_p) > -1 || $.inArray("4", d_p) > -1) /* values admitted in data-property */
      && ($.inArray("2", d_l) > -1 || $.inArray("4", d_l) > -1) /* values admitted in data-location */
      && ($.inArray("3", d_f) > -1 || $.inArray("4", d_f) > -1) /* values admitted in data-format */
      /* add as many filters you need */
};
```

and select with

```
$('li:myProductFiltered')
```

see a live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VgTnG/

Answer (score 1):

You could [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the `li` elements and use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) to create arrays of the values of the various `data-*` attributes. You can then use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to test for the presence of various values in those arrays:

```
$("li").filter(function() {
    var li = $(this),
        property = li.data("property").split(","),
        format = li.data("format").split(","),
        location = li.data("location").split(",");
    return (property.indexOf("2") > -1 || property.indexOf("4") > -1) && (format.indexOf("4") > -1 || format.indexOf("5") > -1);
});
```

The above example would return all `li` elements with a value of 2 or 4 in `data-property` and a value of 4 or 5 in `data-format`. You can add in as many conditions as you need, just make sure you group them correctly with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this http://jsfiddle.net/sabri/gmt8m/

```
var conditions = {
    'data-format': ['4', '1'],
    'data-location': ['5', '2']

}

var result = $('li').filter(function(index) {
    var current_li = $(this);
    var and_cond = true;
    $.each(conditions, function(key, value) {
        var or_cond = false;
        $.each(value, function(skey, svalue) {
            or_cond = or_cond || (jQuery.inArray(svalue, current_li.attr(key).split(',')) != -1 )
        })
            and_cond = and_cond && or_cond;
    })
    if(and_cond )
       return current_li ;


})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this does not work. When using

<li data-property="2,3,4" data-format="1,2,3,4,5" data-location="1,2,4" data-id="9">
                        Product A is fantastic
</li>
<li data-property="2,3,4" data-format="9" data-location="1,2,4" data-id="9">
                        Product B is fantastic
</li> as input Product B is returned as well

Comment: I used this conditions array

var conditions = {
    'data-format': ['4', '1'],
    'data-location': ['5', '2']

}

and only A has been selected
check the console.


check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sabri/b6WKn/